# Same Magento 2 htaccess file but different results on local machine and live server

Tags: magento-2.1, htaccess

I am running Magento 2.1.14 and have a version installed on my local machine as well as a live server.  Both machines are running Apache 2.2.  On my local machine I installed php 7.0.31 and on the live server (shared hosting) I am using php 7.0.31 for my domain.  The default setting for the live server is php 5.6.  I have SSL setup on both and run through https.  I have mod_rewrite enabled on both servers as well.

I have the same htaccess file on both hosts and an identical file tree.  They are identical copies of each other, except for the base and secure URL's.  When I navigate to a literal URL on my local machine, it shows the proper page.  But when I navigate to the literal URL on my live server, it gives me a 404 page.

**EDITED**
For Example:

https://127.0.0.1/magento.com/testDirectory/phpInfo.php

Where [magento.com] is the name of the directory where my magento store is installed, will show me the page.

BUT

https://magento.com/testDirectory/phpInfo.php
Where [magento.com] is my domain, will throw me a 404 page.

I don't have a large .htaccess file and I'm posting the rewrites section below to see if anyone might be able to tell me why I can view the literal path on my local machine, but my live server is showing me a 404.  Also, which action is correct (showing me the page, or throwing the 404), based on my htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
#added below redirect rule for wordpress - redirects for posts
RewriteRule ^.(\d{0,4})/(.*)$ /blog/$2 [L,R=301]
#added below redirect rule for wordpress - because we deleted the blog category
RewriteRule ^blog/category/blog/(.+)? /blog/$1 [L,R=301]
#added below redirect rule for wordpress - removed catgegory tag in uri
RewriteRule ^blog/category/(.+)? /blog/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If magento.com is directory second example don't have full address. It's like https://directory/testDirectory

Comment: Could you clarify?  That didn’t make sense.  Second example has the full address.

Comment: your example is different 1. https://localhost/directory/... and 2 is https://directory/...    (should be https://domain/directory)  When You add rewrite it will be only https://localhost/ and https://domain.com without magento directory

Comment: Bart, gonna edit,  sorry, the first example [magento.com] is a directory name on my localhost.  It’s where my magento is installed.  On live server [magento.com] would be the actual domain.

Comment: Hi Jason Did you try to experiment with RewriteBase? Check also settings what is your default webroot in apache2 /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
/etc/apache/apache2.conf

Comment: @BartZalas I haven’t experimented with the rewrite base because to be honest I didn’t know how that would affect the site.  Do I need to uncomment the rewrite base for the rewrites to work properly on both my local server and the live server?  Up until now I haven’t uncommented any of the rewrite bases. My default webroot on local hosts is 127.0.0.1.  On the live server, I can’t fet the full path, but my magento is installed in my root public_html directory.

Comment: So on your server is public_html_/ and your Magento app and rest or public_html/some directory/ Magento files ?

Comment: On the live server it would be public_html/(all my magento files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that all your files are in directory magento.com

so add this:

```
RewriteBase /magento.com/
```

or

```
RewriteBase /var/www/html/magento.com/
```

Comment: Not working....